# Send mail from multiple accounts that are the same account but belongs to different domains

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app

I've a single email server that is the same server for the following domains:

- myprivatedomain.com
- mycompany.com

Say I've an account on that server, for example "me"

So I've two email addresses for the same account

- me@myprivatedomain.com
- me@mycompany.com

Both email addresses are "the same" and at the server side there is no distinction. It is physically the same income folder and this is the desired behavior.

In a typical situation, when I write an email I decide if the email "FROM" will be *me@myprivatedomain.com* or *me@mycompany.com*

In order to properly set up Mail.app in my mac I need to create two different email accounts. I cannot simply create one "inactive" and another "active" account as I do in Outlook. Mail app is connecting twice to the email server and displaying twice the same information.

How can I set up Mail.app in order to have only one connection to the server and have the possibility to decide the mail that will appear at the FROM field of the email?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22279?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

## Create or change an alias

1. Choose Mail > Preferences, then click Accounts.
2. Select an account, then click Account Information.
3. Click the Alias pop-up menu, choose Edit Aliases, then do one of the following:

## Send a message from an alias

In a new message, move the pointer over the From field, click the pop-up menu that appears, then choose an email alias.